# Примеры написание блога на Реакте?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Всем привет.
я новичок в реакте, и прошу вашей помощи.

Есть ли у кого опыт написания блога на реакте, или примеры как написать ?
Я создав два компонента , PostList and PostSingle, пост лист я вывожу список всех постов , и краткую информацию, и у меня стоит проблема передачи данных при клике на определенную статью чтобы я мог открывать статью целиком ?

Спасибо )

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае Вам лучше всего воспользоваться роутингом, сам пользовался [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start), в реакте при использовании этого пакета при изменении url'а можно менять содержимое сайта, таким образом на Вашем месте я бы сделал 2 страницы: одну со всеми постами, другую с одним постом и информацией о нем и менял бы при клике url наподобие "/post/:postId", где postId - id'шник поста, по которому произошел клик. Легче всего будет обернуть каждый пост в компонент [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink), в аттрибуте "to" которого указать нужный путь. Реагировать на изменение url'а будут комоненты [Route](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route).Route для отдельных постов должен получать в качестве параметра id одного из них и в зависимости от него уже отрисовывать нужный.В компоненте с постами легче всего будет получать параметры с url'а с помощью хука [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams). Советую ознакомиться с документацией на сайте данного пакета и изучить хотя бы основы роутинга в React.